# No rule to make target error when using Make to compile chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, makefile, compiler-errors, google-nativeclient

I'm revisiting an old Chrome App project and have all the SDKs (Pepper 49) installed and Python etc.

My previous project folder is accepted by Chrome in Dev mode and runs.

However, I now need to add to the project and the build/make process is showing the error below:

[image]

The directory tree I used last has changed, which is why I've highlighted the full directory my project is in.

Is this as simple as Make.exe not supporting string gaps in the directory names? The error implies this could be the case.

Comment: I guess you're right, the error info seems to indicate the path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a quoting problem. The spaces aren't quoted on the command line so they are being seen as significant by the shell and `STAMPDIR` is being set to only `V:/Code` while `Repositories/BCS` and `Chrome/BCS` are being seen as additional command line arguments to `make` and `make` assumes they are targets to build (and can't do so).

You'll need to quote the argument in the makefile so that it gets put on the command line correctly.